# Make partition grub in read-only

Tags: grub2, kernel

I need to make one partition "hd0,gpt4" read-only during boot for testing purposes. I have grub.cfg file, but I don't know how I can tell to him to make this partition read-only before boot.

My setup is Windows + ISO Ubuntu added to grub.

My possible command:

[image: Grub Command]